# How to print list in opposite direction?

Tags: php, html, mysql

My question is by default list print in top to bottom direction but I want to print in bottom to top direction which means first value should be at bottom and last value on top.

```
<?php 
$query="select name from plant ";
$q=mysqli_query($con,$query)or die("Could Not Perform the Query");
$hh = '';
while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc())
{
$hh .= '<li><a href="#">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>';
}
?>
<ul id="myUL">
<?php echo $hh; ?> 
</ul>
```

### By default it will print:-

Mango

Apple

Grape

### But I want:-

Grape

Apple

Mango

Comment: You would normally add an ORDER BY clause to your SQL, but not sure what order they are in currently.

Comment: Okay man I will try..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the order of results by select query you must create an additional field on the table where you define the order of the single element, after that you can use the select statement and order them by new field.
For example, you have theese columns on the table:

id, name, order_column, created_at

and you have 3 records on this table:
1, pippo, 1, 2019-02-10
2, pluto, 5, 2019-02-10
3, topolino, 3, 2019-02-10

where the third column is the order of element on the column, if you want to order by its you should use a query like this

```
  select name from table_name order by order_column ASC
```

or

```
  select name from table_name order by order_column DESC
```

that's it!

Comment: I used this:-   ol { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

li {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

Comment: It is not the correct form, u must manage data not the html elements

Answer (score 0):

You should handle sorting with SQL query but you can also achieve this in PHP. Save the result into an array and reverse the order of rendering.

```
<?php 

  $plants = array(); 
  while( $row = $q->fetch_assoc() ) {
     $plants = $row['name'];
  }

  $index = count( $plants );
?>

<ul id="myUL">
  <?php while( $index ) { ?>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $plants[--$index]; ?></a></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

You can also try [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

Answer (score -1):

This is quite simple. Sort your query results in descending order:

```
select name from plant order by name desc
```

Comment: I used this:- ol { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

li {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}